# How can I get the exteriorRing of a polygon with C++ geos

Tags: c++, geos

After using CascadedPolygonUnion, I need to get the exterior of the resulted polygon.

I made a geometry collection then combine two polygons using CascadedPolygonUnion function. Then try to get exterior coords of resulting geometry (polygon) using getExteriorRing.

```
std::vector<geos::geom::Polygon*> geomCollection; 
geomCollection.push_back(poly1);
geomCollection.push_back(poly2);
geos::geom::Geometry* unionedPoly =
geos::operation::geounion::CascadedPolygonUnion::Union(
&geomCollection);
std::cout<<unionedPoly->getGeometryType()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<unionedPoly->getExteriorRing()<<std::endl;
```

it gives this error message: class geos::geom::Geometry’ has no member named ‘getExteriorRing’
I think either my CascadedPolygonUnion is wrong or I need to cast to geometry to polygon

What do I have to do?
regards

Comment: the return value of `CascadedPolygonUnion::Union` is not a polygon, it is a `geometry` which does not have `getExteriorRing` member function.

Comment: thank you, how can I convert resulting geometry to polygon?

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` to convert `Geometry` to `Polygon`. If result is not nullptr you can use `getExteriorRing` on returned Polygon.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Geos. By language syntax you can do ```geos::geom::Polygon* p = dynamic_cast<geos::geom::Polygon*>(unionedPoly)``` if its failed , that's mean you cant :)

Comment: "zapredelom" thank you. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a polygon/vector of polygons like this:

```
vector<Polygon*> polyList;
switch (unionedPoly->getGeometryTypeId())
{
    case GeometryTypeId::GEOS_POLYGON:
    {
        polyList.push_back(dynamic_cast<geos::geom::Polygon*>(unionedPoly));
        return polyList;
    }
    case GeometryTypeId::GEOS_MULTIPOLYGON:
    case GeometryTypeId::GEOS_GEOMETRYCOLLECTION:
    {
        auto collection = dynamic_cast<geos::geom::GeometryCollection*>(unionedPoly);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)collection->getNumGeometries(); i++)
        {   // clone().release() because it's const
            polyList.push_back(dynamic_cast<geos::geom::Polygon*>(collection->getGeometryN(i)->clone().release()));
        }
        return polylist;
    }
    default:
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid geometry type ID");    
}
```

you can just use the first case if you're certain the polygons are connected and it will only return the one polygon.